# Eval scope in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, eval

Please help.

=Does not work:

```
Function f()
    f = 1
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click()
    k = Eval("f()")
End Sub
```

=Does not work:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    с=1
    k = Eval("с")
End Sub
```

=Do work:

```
Function f()
    f = 1
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click()
    k = f()
End Sub
```

=In help:
The following example assumes that you have a series of 50 functions defined as A1, A2, and so on. This example uses the Eval function to call each function in the series.

```
Sub CallSeries()
    Dim intI As Integer
    For intI = 1 To 50
        Eval("A" & intI & "()")
    Next intI
End Sub
```

How to make variant 1 work?

Thanks in advance.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

=UPDATE:
The number of error I get with "Does not work" sections is 2425. "Can not find the name of the function." (or "Can not find the name of the expression." in the second case). Sorry for my English.

=UPDATE:
When I try explicitly name the function in Eval:

```
 k = Eval("[Forms]![Form1].f()")
```

I get error 31005 - "Access can not calculate expression because there is a reference to "f"". I start to be suspicious of Access prohibiting use of user-defined functions and variables in Eval. Though help states opposite.

=UPDATE:
Do work:

```
    Function f()
        f = 1
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click()
        k = Eval("val(""551" & "9" & "6"")")
    End Sub
```

Very strange rules of double-quoting, as for me. But this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Please expand on "Does not work".

Comment: I do not really know how. That's all I have.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Does k=2? Does your computer catch on fire? *What does "doesn't work" mean?*

Comment: See updates and answer on joseph4tw's question for expanded and additional information. There are currently 3 different types of error.

Answer (score 5):

The `Eval` function cannot access functions that are in `Form` modules. Place the function in an ordinary `Module`.

Answer (score 1):

There is one interesting fact. Eval() does not accept user variables as arguments, but accepts form controls data.